# Is it okay to add new properties to Redux state during state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have my initial Redux state like this:

```
const initialState = {
   product: {
     name: '',
     itemId: 0,
     value: 0
   },
};
```

When `LOAD_PRODUCTS` action is dispatched, I wanted to add a new property `relatedProducts: []` to `product.` Is it okay thing to do in Redux? Or do I still need to have the `relatedProducts` in the initialState?

Comment: why not define it from the start as `null`?

Comment: @SagiRika Am I breaking any rules by not doing that?

Comment: I wouldn't say that you are breaking any rule. But it's a good practice to have all the properties available in the initialState. Think that someone can maintain this code later and will rely on that initialState as the only posible keys to grab of that part of the store.